# Building CUDA extension fails even after issue in code (deprecated AT_CHECK) is fixed

Tags: python, c++, pytorch

I'm trying to install [neural_renderer](https://github.com/daniilidis-group/neural_renderer). Unfortunately, the original implementation only supports Python 2.7+ and PyTorch 0.4.0, so I'm using a fork that includes some fixes for compatibility with torch 1.7 ([here](https://github.com/ZhengZerong/neural_renderer)). The main issue was using `AT_CHECK()`, which was not compatible with newer versions of PyTorch, and was replaced with `TORCH_CHECK()`.

After running `pip install neural_renderer_pytorch` on the fixed version, using a virtual environment, I get the output (which I truncated to just the error):

```
 /tmp/pip-install-[somestring]/neural-renderer-pytorch_[somelongstring]/neural_renderer/cuda/load_textures_cuda.cpp:15:23: error: ‘AT_CHECK’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘DCHECK’?
       15 | #define CHECK_CUDA(x) AT_CHECK(x.type().is_cuda(), #x " must be a CUDA tensor")
          |                       ^~~~~~~~
```

with [somestring] and [somelongstring] being some alphanumeric strings that changed with each compilation.

It looks like `AT_CHECK` is still being used somewhere in the code, but I don't know where. I know this error is exactly what the fork fixed, so I *assume* the cpp file is still cached somewhere from a previous compilation. But I can't figure out where exactly. I'm sure I'm on branch pytorch1.7 and running pip in the right repository; with torch==1.7.0 installed.

What I've tried so far, to no avail:

- run `pip cache purge` before attempting to install
- running pip with `--no-cache-dir`
- deleting the virtualenv I'm using and making a new one
- deleting the entire repository and making a new one

[This issue](https://github.com/daniilidis-group/neural_renderer/issues/67) on GitHub suggested just using PyTorch 1.4.0. This worked (i.e. I created a Python3.7 environment and ran `conda install pytorch==1.4.0 torchvision==0.5.0 cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch`, then installed), but my goal is still to compile it for PyTorch 1.7.0 (and a newer version of Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install the fork, you cannot use `pip install neural_renderer_pytorch`. This command installs the original one.

To install the fork, you have to clone it to your local machine and install it:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/ZhengZerong/neural_renderer
cd neural_renderer
pip install .
```

You can do it in just one go as well:

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/ZhengZerong/neural_renderer.git
```

Don't forget to uninstall the original version first, or just start a new venv.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I assume running `pip install neural_renderer_pytorch` installs it from PyPI. The package name uses dashes instead of underscores on PyPI, which is why I had assumed it couldn't find it, and it was looking in the setup.py of the current dir to find the package. But it looks like pip doesn't care if it's a dash or an underscore.